# Ajax refresh does not refresh the Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a JSP page that refreshes every 5 seconds Using ajax.
The page i am calling having javascript that is not getting refreshed .
Please tell me how to achieve that.

Below is the code i am using to refresh that page .

refresh is the name of the div where i am displaying the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AutoRefresh() {
        var xmlHttp;
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    alert("No AJAX");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            //alert("hi");
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {

                document.getElementById('TotalRoutes').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;

                setTimeout('AutoRefresh()', 10 * 1000); // JavaScript function calls AutoRefresh() every 3 seconds
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "QAGENIE.jsp", true);

        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

Here js files in the QAGENIE.jsp page is not getting refreshed on the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(AutoRefresh,5000);` for every 5 seconds

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
```

window.onload = AutoRefresh();

Comment: I dont think auto window.location.reload(); is required because this will reload the whole page .I want only part of the page to be refreshed.In my refresh is also happening only javascript of the refreshing page is not reloading

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling AutoRefresh function first time. so nothing will be execute. and if you are calling from outside of your code which you gave here, then please post whole web page code in question.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `document.getElementById('TotalRoutes').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;`, script tags inside the `"QAGENIE.jsp"` ***are not executed***, that's why:

> js files in the QAGENIE.jsp page is not getting refreshed.

Since the question is tagged with jQuery, you could try `$.ajax` and `$.html`. Like this:

```
 function AutoRefresh(){
       $.ajax({
          url:"QAGENIE.jsp"
       })
       .done(function(response){
           $("#TotalRoutes").html(response);
           setTimeout(AutoRefresh,10*1000); 
       });
    }

AutoRefresh(); //call this to trigger the first call
```

- `$.html` automatically parses and executes script tags in the response HTML.
- There is 1 more thing to notice is browser cache, if your js files are cacheable (as it usually does by the cache response header from server), the js files may be served from the cached. If you need to always refresh with new js files, ensure your js files are not returned with a cache header, or try to append a random string at the end of the script tags. Like this:

  `<script src="yourFile.js?[randomstring]"></script>`